# awk 2 perl conversion

Tags: perl, awk

I'm trying to convert this awk function to perl, it parses an apache log file and print entries created in the past minute.

```
awk vDate=$(date -d'now-1 minutes' +[%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S]) '$4 > Date '
```

I'm new to perl, and I'm now sure how I can entorplate system function `$(date -d'now-1 ..etc)` to perl.

Comment: Are you sure the comparison `>` in awk can compare dates in this format correctly?

Comment: Try [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece), see [Solve almost any datetime need with Time::Piece](http://perltricks.com/article/59/2014/1/10/Solve-almost-any-datetime-need-with-Time--Piece/)

Comment: You can do a system call in Perl with backticks `$ perl -e '$d=\`date\`; print $d'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Time::Piece](http://p3rl.org/Time::Piece):

```
perl -MTime::Piece -ane '
    BEGIN { $now = time }
    print if Time::Piece->strptime($F[3], "[%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S]")->epoch
          > $now - 60' access_log
```

You can also use `$^T` instead of `$now`, you can then delete the whole BEGIN block.

```
perl -MTime::Piece -ane '
    print if Time::Piece->strptime($F[3], "[%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S]")->epoch
          > $^T - 60' access_log
```